# TCP server done multithread , parsing messages in events

Tags: multithreading, events, tcp

I have a task in a TCP server (Java) that is going to send and accept messages. I need to do it in a multithread manner. While I have no problem with that part, my issue is that the parsing of the messages needs to be in a separate class in the shape of an event. How do I do that?

Comment: Not sure I understand.  You want to fire the event upon completed assembly of an application-level message?

Comment: Sorry! I am new in programming maybe i did not put my question right !

Comment: So i need to make a class witch will accept TCP connexions and will send messages. The process must be multithread.The class needs to have methods for stopping and turning on the server.The message parsing that comes and goes it doesn`t have to be in the same class, it needs to be exposed as an events so that the class that is managing the server to have his own logics